# Port dependent NGINX proxy config

Tags: nginx

I have this NGINX config

```
upstream example-servers-80 {
    server 192.168.10.5:80;
    server 192.168.10.6:80;
}

upstream example-servers-8080 {
    server 192.168.10.5:8080;
    server 192.168.10.6:8080;
}

server {
  server_name  fb.example.com;
  listen 80;

  location /  {
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://example-servers-80;
  }
}

server {
  server_name  fb.example.com;
  listen 8080;

  location /  {
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://example-servers-8080;
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can combine these using a variable for port. I tries using server_port variable but with no success

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream example-servers-80 {
    server 192.168.10.5:80;
    server 192.168.10.6:80;
}

upstream example-servers-8080 {
    server 192.168.10.5:8080;
    server 192.168.10.6:8080;
}

server {
  server_name  fb.example.com;
  listen 80;
  listen 8080;
  location /  {
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://example-servers-$server_port;
  }
}
```

That should do the trick.